# jQuery .load() not working in iPhone only

Tags: jquery, iphone

can someone please help me with the below code?
It is working fine on the desktop and android phones but not in iPhone.

```
$(function(){
$("#div").load('domain.com/?no-cache=' + (new Date()).getTime() + ' #somediv' , function(){
  //Do stuff here
}
});
```

Comment: "not working" is a little vague.  Is there an error?  Does jquery load correctly?  I don't know about "iPhone" - is there a console to view errors?  To debug networking?  Which browser on "iPhone"?

Comment: @freedomn-m jQuery and other ajax requests work fine. Only the .load() method is not working. Browser is Safari on iPhone.

Comment: `.load()` is just a shortcut for `$.ajax()` that calls `$("#div").html(response)`

Comment: So if `$.ajax` works, there's no reason why `.load()` wouldn't work the same.

Comment: Could be that `$.load()` has been overwritten for some nefarious iphone reason - try changing your code from `$.load` to `$.ajax`

Comment: @Barmar I know it is a shortcut but it isn't working at all on iPhone only.

Comment: Then try the alternative

Comment: Had to set the 'cache' property to 'false' for it to work! Phewww! Thanks.